# The Dissection of R4-D2

Tags: dissection

**Edit** - Added hint to help decode the color tiles.

You are back on Tatooine with R4-D2 (a descendant of R2-D2). During the journey to Herogga's pavilion, you encounter a fierce sandstorm. Unfortunately, some of the fine particles have infiltrated R4-D2's drive units.  Serious damage will occur unless the droid is disassembled and cleaned. You know this will not be easy so you look for some guidance and find three **equations**, a small **crossword** puzzle, and some **encoding**.

As your mission is urgent, you proceed to understand the clues and successfully disassemble R4-D2.

The best solution to this puzzle will be the **first to show a correct diagram** of the droid's components.  **Partial answers are OK**.

(The clue to all of the words in the crossword is **four**. The equations and crossword will tell you the number of components and their relative shapes. The encoding provides a little more description of the shapes but is not necessary to solve the disassembly.)

Bonne chance!

**HINT - The encoding sequence was English letters to Base 4 numbers to CMYK colors.**

[image: R4-D4]

Comment: What is the crossword clue?

Comment: Look very intriguing! Oh those distractions......

Comment: @Len could you let us know if you prefer that we crack 'everything' first, or go to it by partial answered (and a common solving attempt as a result?) I think I have some initial ideas, but far from the solution. Also is there a reason the crossword hint is spoiler tagged? Is it *needed* information, or a *hint* ? Maybe clarify this in the OP.

Comment: @BmyGuest - Thanks. OP clarified to better explain the purpose of the clues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit of post:** I start with the solution

Finding the dissection was fiendishly difficult, but here it is:

> [image: Solution]

Now as for the other clues or puzzles:

**The equations** were rather straight forward:

> One can easily see that they build a chain, in the end being written in one line as A≅B≅C≅D=14 which means that we seek 4 congruent tiles a 14 squares. This matches, as the whole puzzle has 4x4=56 squares. Also "4" is the solution of the crossword puzzle and also appears as single number. So now we know how we have to dissect.

**The crossword** was first solved by **shoover**:

> The 4 words are all literally "4" being written in 4 different languages: `vier`, `quatre`, `four` and `tessera`. (German, French, English and Greek, respectively). The Greek `tessera` was written with Greek letters ( `τέσσερα` ) 
>  The *purpose* of the crossword puzzle is somewhat illusive, as 'four' was given as hint and is the only information *gained* by the puzzle. But it is a very nice sub-puzzle enforcing the fact that the dissection should happen into 4 parts.

**The colour code** was first solved by **Volatility**:

> Given the hint that base-4 encoding was used, i.e numbers are formed by:
>  `### = A*0 + B*4 + C*16 + D*64`
>   one could guess that the colours Black, Cyan, Mangenta and Yellow stand for 0, 1, 2, 3 and their position in the field for A,B,C,D. 
>  As numbers are used to represent letters, and standard ASCII letters use the number 65 to 90 for 'A' to 'Z', one could further conclude that the "D*64" needs to be D=1 for *all* letters. This gives two important pieces of information:
>  - The position which has the same colour (top-right) has to by "D" 
>  - The colour which is in this position has to stand for "1" (=Cyan) 
>  From here, it is trial-and error to find one has to go 'clockwise' for D,C,B,A and the colours are 0,1,2,3 for Black, Cyan, Magenta and Yellow respectively. 
>  The fields then spell out `CHAIR` and `STACK` which nicely describes the graphical dissection.

---

---

**History (initial 2 postings and edits)**

## Partial answer / observation.

This is a work-in-progress list of observations and possible leads in this puzzle.

I'm posting, because the OP invites to do so. I also think that if one purpose of the site is to *teach* puzzle-smiths how to improve, this is an important step, because it gives the puzzle-smith feedback on *what reactions his puzzle creates*, even if they are not the intended ones. (So they can be recognized as wanted red herrings, or may be removed by better specification.)

**Observations:**

Tile size and equations:

> **There are 56 tiles and 4 *variables* as well as the numbers 14 & 4.** The equations indicated proportionality or equality and 14*4 is indeed 56, leading to the assumption we have to dissect in 4 equally *sized* but not equally *shaped* tiles.

The crossword:

> **has already been solved (I think) by *shoover* above, with being `vier`, `quatre`, `four` and `tessara` all meaning 4. A nice twist is that Greek letters are used (sigma & rho) for the Greek `tessara`.

The puzzle as a whole:

> 1. There are indications of **mirror operations** like the mirrored "r" in the top left.
>  2.  There are also some (6) tiles which are graphics which seem to be puzzle-tiles of an image representing a R2D2 (or R4D2 ?) They are not complete. These might be *filler* without meaning or they may come in later?
>  3. There are 7 empty tiles. Maybe they are needed to counterbalance the bitmap tiles of point 2. ?
>  4. Colours in the colour-tiles are the prime colours of subtractive colour mixing (*printing colours*). which at the same time make them result-colours of additional colour mixing (*screen colours*). It might therefore be, that they represent an *overlay* of colours.

---

Having spent a little more time on it, I

> **...am frustrated :c)**
> From the equation A=B=C=D=14 it seems that there should be 4 congruent shapes of 14 tiles which dissect the R4-D2. 
>  If this is indeed the case, the other (colour) hints would not be needed, and one could simply attempt a regular 2D dissection puzzle into 4 congruent shapes.

So far so good, but...

> I simply can not find it, and having tested similar shapes "growing" I'm getting more and more suspicious that there is no such solution...

Which makes me wonder:

> Am I making the wrong assumption tempted by the regular square grid? Do the shapes have to by polyominos? I'm no longer sure about that at all...

Or...

> Is this for sure only a 2D puzzle? Or are we dealing with a clever 2D projection of a 3D puzzle?

Taking the 2nd thought further:

> Each section would have 14 squares - which fits to the surface area of any 3-cube part. (3x6 minus 3x2 border walls ) This would also nicely fit to the colour-bitmaps if they depict in a certain way such 3-cube L arrangements. Not sure how though. 
>  Would this work in 3D in principle? 3x4=12cubes would have a maximum surface area of 12x6 - 11x2 = 50 if they are touching one space each. Hmm...

Comment: @Len: FOUND IT! Difficult but finally...

Comment: CONGRATULATIONS!  I also learned a lot from all the feedback.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you.  Those are great suggestions.  And there is nothing more to be discovered.  I'll re-edit the OP after a little more thought (don't want it to be very inconsistent with the answers and comments) ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Only a partial answer here, based on the crossword clue.

> The crosswords are "four" in different languages: `vier` (German) and `quatre` (French) across, and `four` (English) and `tessara` (Greek) down.

Comment: @Len: Very nice twist with the sigma and rho letters.

Comment: +1, but "four" is "τέσσερα" or "tessera". Small typo.

Comment: 四 is also 4 in chinese.

Answer (score 4):

## Partial answer

Random symbols:

> The symbols 4, 四, and Δ' all have a relation to the number 4: the first symbol is obvious, 四 is the Chinese character for 4, and Δ' in quadratic equations is Δ/4 (where Δ is the discriminant). These symbols (I believe) serve as a clue to the crossword puzzle. The backwards 'r' does seem to suggest some sort of mirroring, as @BmyGuest has stated.

Crossword:

> As the answers above say, the answers are 'vier', 'tessera', 'quatre', and 'four', the words for the number 4 in German, Greek, French and English respectively.

Equations:

> Put together, the equations say A≅B≅C≅D=14. The '≅' symbol is the standard symbol for congruency in geometry, hinting that A, B, C and D are congruent shapes. 14*4=56, which is the number of tiles, supporting the idea of congruency.

Encoding:

> Since @Len was gracious enough to give us a hint, all I had to do was figure out which numbers the colours stood for, and what order they were in. Because the ordinal numbers for 'A' to 'Z' were 65 to 90, I figured that the first number would always be 1. The corner with the same colour in each symbol was the top right, with cyan. Using that, I guessed that C=1, M=2, Y=3, and K=0. Then it was a case of trial and error figuring out what order they were in. This worked out to be a clockwise "circle" starting from the top right, yielding the message "CHAIR STACK".

The graphics and empty tiles:

> Haven't figured those out yet.